# Relationship between $_nC_2$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations

$$_nC_2 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

and so is the following sum: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

I'm curious if there's any ingenious alternative interpretation of the combination $_nC_2$ in terms of the sum of numbers.

Comment: $\binom n2$ is the number of $2-$subsets of $S=\{1,2,...,n\}$. We can pair $1$ with $2,...,n$ giving $n-1$ subsets, $2$ with $3,4,...,n$ giving $n-2$ subsets and so on till the final subset $\{n-1,n\}$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Wow, thanks! Had you written it as an answer I would've definitely accepted :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of a square consisting of $n \times n$ unit squares. A diagonal of the square contains $n$ unit squares and it splits the rest of the square into $2$ equally sized "triangles" of $x$ unit squares each. We then have
$$n+2x=n^2 \Rightarrow x=\binom{n}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\sum_{k=m}^{n}{k \choose m}={n+1 \choose n+1}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k=\frac{1}{2} n(n+1)$$
Alternatively
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k \choose 1}={n+1 \choose 2}=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$$